in outlook365 a few messages, with correct timestamp in the main view, are shown with wrong timestamps when opened in their separate message window
Using the standalone native windows outlook program
( Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2410 Build 16.0.18129.20100) 64-bit on a laptop with win11 22H2)
I have just discovered that a few emails, that are shown with the correct timestamp (consistent with the one reported in the body message)
in the main folder list view,
are then, when opened in their separate message window, reported with the wrong timestamp (an 1-hour shift in the future)
(NB: the issue is NOT present when using the Outlook365 web interface so i would be tempted to assume that the issue is in the windows program)

I have searched for the same issue here and found a previous question where the culprit was the use of the modified vs received field - but, as show in the screenshot, this does not apply to my problem

At least I have found that this issue was also reported in another post from ~10 months ago - unfortunately even in that thread no fix was suggested
